# Is SKLearn's KS Test Implementation Wrong?

Tags: scikit-learn

I was looking at the implementation for the KS TEST in sklearn here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.5.0/scipy/stats/stats.py#L6580-L6745

```
data1 = np.sort(data1)
data2 = np.sort(data2)
n1 = data1.shape[0]
n2 = data2.shape[0]
data_all = np.concatenate([data1, data2])
# using searchsorted solves equal data problem
cdf1 = np.searchsorted(data1, data_all, side='right') / n1
cdf2 = np.searchsorted(data2, data_all, side='right') / n2
cddiffs = cdf1 - cdf2
```

The basic concept is to map the sorted inputs to the whole dataset and inspect the differences in the CDF. However, shouldn't you sort the whole dataset first so that the search sorted algorithm correctly matches to the distribution?

```
data_all = np.sort(np.concatenate([data1, data2]))
```

I seem to get the same metric for cdf1 and cdf2 without and with sorting data_all, but the values for cdf1 and cdf2 are different. Maybe I'm missing some mathematical reason why the metric is the same, but the resulting cdfs are different.